Let $\alpha_{ij}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n}~p_{ij}^m,~~i,j\in S.$ Show that above limit exist.
Consider an irreducible markov chain with finite state space $S$. let $P=[(p_{ij})]$ is given transition probability matrix and $p^n=[(p_{ij}]$ denote the $n-$ step transition matrix for the chain. Let $$\alpha_{ij}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n}~p_{ij}^m,~~i,j\in S.$$


Show that above limit exist.




$\alpha_{ij}=\alpha_{kj}\forall~~i,j,k\in S$.


Now there are two cases
First case: If chain is aperiodic, since it has only one communication class and states are finite every state is reccurent which implies $\sum_{m=1}^{n}~p_{ij}^m$ diverges. This implies  $\lim_{n\to\infty} p_{ij}^n\neq0$
Then by cauchy first limit theorem $$\lim_{n\to\infty} ~p_{ij}^n=\lim_{n\to\infty} ~p_{kj}^n$$
this proves part 2.
Any hints for periodic case?

Your first argument for the aperiodic case doesn't make much sense. Try to prove $p^n_{i,j}$ converge to a number $\pi(j)$ instead. For the periodic case, $p_{ij}^m$ is only positive at $m = kd$, where $d$ is the period of the chain, so the limit can be rewritten as $\sum_{n}....p^{nd}_{ij}$ and use that $P^d$ is aperiodic.

Can you elaborate about limit more on periodic case

I have written an answer below, the previous comment was not so precise...

Suppose the period of the chain is $d>1$, then you can always decompose all the states into $d$ groups $A_1,...,A_d$ such that, from any state $i \in A_k$, it's only possible to jump to the next group $A_{k+1}$ with the convention $d+1 = 1$.
For each $k=1,...,d$ we have
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} P^{k+nd}  = P^k\Pi_d $$
where $\Pi_d$ is a limiting matrix of $P^{nd}$. This is because the matrix $P^d$ is reducible, but the classes $A_1,...,A_d$ are disjoint and $P^d$-ergodic. By restricting to these subclasses, we have an ergodic (irreducible + aperiodic) chain, and thus $P^{nd}(x,y)$ converges to some constant $\Pi(y)$ (independent of $x$) for any $(x,y)$ belongs to the same subclass.
As a consequence,
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=1}^{n} P^{m} =  \left(\frac{1}{d}\sum_{m=0}^{d-1} P^m \right)\Pi_d $$
and so you can check $\alpha_{i,j} = \frac{\Pi(j)}{d}$, where $\Pi(j) = \Pi_d(z,j), \ \forall z$ belongs to the same group of $j$. Indeed, we know more than that: Let $A := (\alpha_{ij})$ then $\pi A = \pi$ (from the limit), where $\pi$ is the unique invariant measure of $P$. Now
$$ \pi(j) = \pi A (j) = \sum_{i}\pi(i)\alpha_{ij}= \alpha_{ij} = \frac{\Pi(j)}{d}$$
and thus this limit is identically $\pi(j)$!
